# sqlce - What do I need to change to make this query work?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I am trying to select two columns of "skill", player1 and player2 respectively. The query works if I delete "player2" but then only returns the player1 skill.

So my question is, what do I need do differently on this query to get it to select skill from both player1 and player2, vs just one or the other. Thanks.

```
SELECT        skill
FROM            player
WHERE        (id IN
                         (SELECT        player1,player2
                           FROM            temp_table
                           WHERE        (school = 0)))
ORDER BY weight
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a join instead:

```
SELECT        p.skill
FROM          player p
INNER JOIN    temp_table t  ON p.id IN (t.player1, t.player2)
WHERE         t.school = 0
ORDER BY      p.weight
```